# Superglobals: PHP security

Tags: php, security

Is it possible for a client to modify PHP superglobal variables, especially $_SERVER, somehow - maybe not in a common way?

In other words, is this code secure:

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
   ob_clean();
   echo @file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/404.html');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is fine - `SERVER_NAME` can't be modified. The ones to be careful with are `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, as a user could add some js to the address bar - if these are written out to the screen they should be carefully escaped.

Your code is fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine.

No user can change any variable of your code unless you leave it open to them using some sort of POST/GET/COOKIE etc

On a side note, if the file is on your server, why are you using file_get_contents()?

Comment: As a workaround. This will return custom Joomla! website page as 404 error page, preserving **HTTP 404 Not found** header. It's the simplest and most SEO-friendly way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since the `$_SERVER` variable only contains data related to the web server that the script is being executed on, I don't see any potential security issues unless the web server itself has been compromised. In that case, you've got a lot bigger problem on your hands. The main exception to this rule is if you use `PHP_SELF` or `REQUEST_URI` since those values can be altered via user input in the URL bar.